# How to lengthen the update interval or reduce the number of steps of jQuery's .animate() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Animating with jQuery is straightforward. Here's an example of animating a number from 0 to 1000 over 2 seconds:

```
var $h1 = $('h1'),
    startValue = parseInt($h1.text(), 10),
    endValue = parseInt($h1.data('end-value'), 10);
$({ int: startValue })
  .animate({
    int: endValue
  }, {
    duration: 2 * 1000,
    step: function () {
      $h1.text(Math.ceil(this.int));
    }
  });
```

*Working example: http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/NpjyJE?editors=1010#0*

This animation looks nice, but makes it difficult to read the number at any point during the animation, as the next number replaces it within milliseconds. Ideally, I'd like to animate the number over the same length of time but using fewer steps (increasing the length of the update interval), so that it's easier to read the number at a glance as it animates.

It doesn't appear that jQuery offers direct control over the number of steps in the animation, nor the update interval; it only seems to accept a [`step` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that receives an interpolated value.

Is there a way to adjust the number of steps that jQuery uses to interpolate the animation over its duration?

Comment: You seem to have answered your question :)

Comment: Yes and no - my approach works, but isn't optimal. Being able to reduce the calls to `step` would be preferable from a performance standpoint, but that's what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: What is expected result? To display sampling of the current `step`, or each step in sequence? The total `duration` of the animation is only `2 * 1000`. Are you trying to display each number for two seconds?

Comment: @guest271314 The expected visual result would be the same as my answer below. Under the hood, I'd like jQuery to call `step` less frequently over the course of the 2 second animation, rather than calling it however many times it typically does and my code having to basically "discard" every call except for the 8th, 16th, 24th, 32nd, etc.

Comment: Does your Answer resolve Question? Is post intended as canonical Question/Answer? See  [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I used to simulate this, which probably works well enough for everyday purposes. This isn't ideal from a performance standpoint, though, because jQuery still calls the `step` function the same number of times as it would have originally.

```
var $h1 = $('h1'),
    startValue = parseInt($h1.text(), 10),
    endValue = parseInt($h1.data('end-value'), 10),
    stepCounter = 0,
    showNthStep = 8;
$({ int: startValue })
  .animate({
    int: endValue
  }, {
    duration: 2 * 1000,
    step: function () {
      if (stepCounter++ === showNthStep) {
        $h1.text(Math.ceil(this.int));        
        stepCounter = 0;
      }
    },
    complete: function () {
      $h1.text(Math.ceil(this.int));        
    }
  });
```

*Working example: http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/NpjYWo?editors=1010#0*

This uses the variable `stepCounter` to count the calls to the `step` function and only update the number every 8th time (per `showNthStep`).

Note that the `complete` function is necessary to update the number one final time if the `step` function isn't called a multiple of 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in front of your code

**jQuery.fx.interval** = 1000;

Default is 13 millisecounds
But the disadvantage is a global setting for all JQuery animations.